# Marklogic forest disappeared from the forests list in the admin page

Tags: marklogic

I tried to rename a forest in a Marklogic 8 database, but the forest disappeared from the forests list in the admin page. I still can access the forest from the file system. If I try to access the forest using the ID through Marklogic I get the error "ADMIN-NOSUCHFOREST: No such forest".

I renamed the forest through the admin page/ forests/ clicked on the forest link and changed the name from the forest configuration page.

How to make the forest visible to Marklogic?

Comment: Are you sure the same forest is available on the filesystem? If so there should be a file called label in which you will find the forest id under the node <master-forest />. I would start by comparing that number with number that gives you an error

Comment: Thank you Chris. Yes, in the file system the forest exists. There is no link to the forest in the forests list in the admin page. I copied the <master-forest> ID and tried to put it in the HTTP request to get a forest, it states that it does not exist.

Comment: I think you should include in your question information about how you renamed. i.e. did you use the admin console or REST or xquery.

Comment: I edited the question description to include the process I used to rename the forest.

Comment: Which version (exactly) are you running, and on what OS?

Comment: Marklogic 8.0-3 on Red Hat 6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very unusual. I've never seen something like this happen myself. If you are entitled to support, I would suggest reaching out to them to report this.

Next to this, there are ways to go about with this, but if your data is important to you, make a copy/backup first.

Now, I can't really think of a particular reason why this happened, but there is a number of things you can look at yourself. One of the first things I would look at is the ErrorLog.txt. If the forest is still in the cluster configuration, then there might be vital hints in the ErrorLog as to what is going wrong.

Next to that you could also look at the files located at /var/opt/MarkLogic/. That is where the cluster configuration files are located. Among them are files called assignments.xml, and older copies named assignments_[0-9].xml. This file tells MarkLogic which forest is located where, and on which host it lives. It might be worthwhile to compare assignments.xml with assignments_1.xml.

I don't recommend this, particularly if you are running a cluster, but you could go inside that file, and edit it, or perhaps restore the assignments_1.xml file. If you really want to experiment with that, make sure to edit those files while the MarkLogic service is down on all relevant hosts, and you do it on all hosts.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you grtjn. The missing forest is not listed in the Assignments.xml file. I do not have privileges to change that file. I requested from the system admin to add a node for the lost forest. I will update the status later. However, I simulated the issue on my local host. Adding a forest information to the Assignments.xml results in a pointer to it in the admin page. Thank you.

Comment: We did the change on assignments.xml. The forest and its content are recovered. Thank you grtjn